# Ansible: "omit place holder" when using Jinja2 filter chaining

Tags: ansible, jinja2

While debugging a condition clause with filter chaining and a check for non-defined variable (`omit`) I found out that the results depend on how a filter is included in a string.

My intention was to make a when-clause for an Ansible task with `value` in a condition. Per "Note" on chaining in [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html), I tried adding `omit` and got the following results.

My playbook:

```
---
- hosts: target
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ value_not_defined|default('0') | int or omit }}"
    - debug: msg="debug {{ value_not_defined|default('0') | int or omit }}"
```

The relevant part of the results:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.2] => {
   "msg": "Hello world!"
}

msg: Hello world!

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.2] => {
    "msg": "debug __omit_place_holder__31268e787e722b495d512986994bcd66ce943a69"
}

msg: debug __omit_place_holder__63eea0d96dd6ed867b95405e11d87dddf61f448d
```

---

Where do the following results come from?

- `Hello world!`
- `__omit_place_holder__63eea0d96dd6ed867b95405e11d87dddf61f448d`

Why the value changes depending on other strings in `debug`'s `msg`?

Comment: Any chance you can share in a comment on the accepted answer how you finally did it? (a when statement with a "possibly non-defined" variable). Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ansible `omit` is a special variable that is used if you don't want to supply a parameter to a module.
So if you pass `arg="{{omit}}"` to a module it is equivalent of not passing `arg` at all.
This is useful if you want to rely on module's default values if your custom parameters are undefined.
There is an example in the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-undefined-variables-and-parameters).

In your example `{{ value_not_defined|default('0') | int or omit }}` is evaluated as follows:

- `None | default('0') | int or omit` *(`None` is used by me here for explanation purpose)*
- `'0' | int or omit`
- `0 or omit`
- `omit`

The last step is because of [boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) in python:

> the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers

With this in mind your tasks are interpreted this way:

```
- debug: msg="{{ omit }}"
- debug: msg="debug {{ omit }}"
```

Resulting in calling the first `debug` without `msg` parameter (that is what `omit` for) and the second `debug` with `msg="debug __omit_place_holder..."` (`omit` is concatenated with `debug` here, so it becomes just an ordinary string).

If `debug` module is called without `msg` parameter, it prints `Hello world!`.